# SQL Server PATINDEX issue/bug when using different case-sensitive collations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, collation, case-sensitive

I have a function (which I found here years ago) that uses `STUFF` / `PATINDEX` to strip out non-alphanumeric characters from a string. When running on a Case Insensitive collation, it works fine. Recently I needed to use it on a Case Sensitive collation DB and found some odd behaviors. If the **%pattern%** for `PATINDEX` is just specifying lower case (ex: **%[^a-z0-9_-]%** ), then all upper case "Z"s are removed when the Collation is **Latin1_General_100_CS_AS**. If the Collation is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS**, then upper case "A"s are removed. Is this a bug or did I miss something?

```sql
USE TestCollation
GO
PRINT '---------SourceString---------'
PRINT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO_Z_A_PQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
GO
ALTER DATABASE TestCollation COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
GO
PRINT '---------SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS---------'
GO

DECLARE @ExternalId VARCHAR(255) =
     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO_Z_A_PQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
DECLARE @return VARCHAR(255)
SET @return = @ExternalId
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9_-]%'
WHILE PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @return = STUFF ( @return, PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ), 1, '' )
END
PRINT @return

go

ALTER DATABASE TestCollation COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS;
GO
PRINT '---------Latin1_General_100_CS_AS---------'
GO
DECLARE @ExternalId VARCHAR(255) =
     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO_Z_A_PQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
DECLARE @return VARCHAR(255)
SET @return = @ExternalId
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9_-]%'
WHILE PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @return = STUFF ( @return, PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ), 1, '' )
END
PRINT @return

ALTER DATABASE TestCollation COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
GO
PRINT '---------SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS---------'
GO
DECLARE @ExternalId VARCHAR(255) =
     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO_Z_A_PQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
DECLARE @return VARCHAR(255)
SET @return = @ExternalId
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9_-]%'
WHILE PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @return = STUFF ( @return, PATINDEX ( @KeepValues, @return ), 1, '' )
END
PRINT @return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is merely a difference in which case comes first when doing case-sensitive sorting. While it might not appear that any sorting is being done, the `[...]` character range wildcard used in both `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` does, in a sense, sort characters when applying a range, such as any `{character}-{character}` pattern (in this case `a-z` and `0-9`). So, the two options are:

1. A**a**BbCc...Z**z** (**a-z** excludes **A**)
2. **a**AbBcC...**z**Z (**a-z** excludes **Z**)

The SQL Server collations (i.e. those having names starting with `SQL_`) mostly use one approach while the Windows collations (i.e. those having names *not* starting with `SQL_`) use the other approach.

To illustrate the behavior:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('Z'), ('z')) tmp (val)
WHERE tmp.val LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
ORDER BY tmp.val COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS;
/*
a
Z
z
*/

SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('Z'), ('z')) tmp (val)
WHERE tmp.val LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
ORDER BY tmp.val COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS;
/*
a
A
z
*/

SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'), ('a'), ('Z'), ('z')) tmp (val)
WHERE tmp.val LIKE '%[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
ORDER BY tmp.val COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;
/*
a
z
*/
```

---

FYI: You can avoid having to deal with the database's default collation by either forcing a collation in the two calls to `PATINDEX`:

```sql
GO
DECLARE @ExternalId VARCHAR(255) =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO_Z_A_PQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
DECLARE @return VARCHAR(255)
SET @return = @ExternalId
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9_-]%'
WHILE PATINDEX ( @KeepValues COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS, @return ) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @return = STUFF ( @return,
                          PATINDEX ( @KeepValues COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS,
                                     @return ),
                          1,
                          '' )
END
PRINT @return
GO
```

*or*, adding `A-Z` to the pattern:

```sql
SET @KeepValues = '%[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  My fix was to add the ```A-Z``` to the pattern.